# Vibration transmission using spring and damper model

Tags: simulations, collision, spring, vibrations

I want to simulate the vibration transmission between two colliding objects. 
I use a Finite Element Model to simulate the vibration on each object, but
I haven't found any good mathematical model to transfer the vibration between
two FEM models that collided and keep in contact.

[image]

In the figure, a sphere is dropped into a plate. the change in color represent
the displacement on the FEM models.

Currently, I am using a spring/damper model to transmit the vibration from 
one object to the other. But, I haven't found any good model that give any 
theoretical foundation to my simple spring/damper model.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by transmitting vibrations. During the contact displacements are constrained between the two parts, with unknown contact force, and outside of contact area displacements are unknown, but the applied force is specified zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for an [elastic half space model](http://www.scientificbulletin.upb.ro/rev_docs_arhiva/full16f_487404.pdf) of a sphere and a plane?

It is unclear from your question what you are trying to achieve here. If you are trying to do an analytical model which is similar to the FEM model then you need to read up on contact mechanics and the elastic half space theory.

For a sphere on a flat plane the force displacement relationship is like

$$ \delta  = \sqrt[3]{\frac{9}{16} \frac{P^2}{r E^2}} $$ where $P$ is the force, $r$ is the sphere radius, and $E$ is the effective combined modulus of elasticity.

For a purely FEM model, then you need a transient analysis with contact elements between your sphere and the plane.

Comment: Thank you for your specific and clear answer, and for the paper. I will check it out and comment about it.

Comment: You are right, I am not so clear about my goal. Using two FEM with arbitrary shape, orientation and material, I want to be able to simulate vibration (energy) transfer between the objects, when these are in contact.

Comment: What you want as I said is a transient simulation (not static) with some kind of contact model.